# How to set GCDWebServerOption_AutomaticallySuspendInBackground to NO

Tags: ios, gcdwebserver

I am new to iOS and swift with some experience in android. I am using the [GCDWebUploader](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer#web-based-uploads-in-ios-apps). Its working fine.

The server suspends when the app is in background. I am aware of the constraints in iOS Background Execution. I dont want to change that behaviour.

But I found in GCDWebServer documentation that we can disable this suspension. Check here https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer#gcdwebserver--background-mode-for-ios-apps. Specifically this part

> If the app goes in the background while no HTTP connections are opened, GCDWebServer will immediately suspend itself and stop accepting new connections as if you had called -stop **(this behavior can be disabled with the ****GCDWebServerOption_AutomaticallySuspendInBackground**** option)**.

How do you set this option. I tried

```
GCDWebServerOption_AutomaticallySuspendInBackground = "NO"
```

And I get the obvious error:

> Cannot assign to value:
>   'GCDWebServerOption_AutomaticallySuspendInBackground' is a 'let'
>   constant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are supposed to pass configuration options using a `NSDictionary` with the following method from a GCDWebServer instance:

```
- (BOOL)startWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)options error:(NSError**)error;
```

**Edit:** a practical example with an *on-the-fly* dictionary in Objective-C:

```
NSError*myError = nil;
self.webServer = [[GCDWebServer alloc] init];
BOOL success = [self.webServer startWithOptions:@{
               GCDWebServerOption_AutomaticallySuspendInBackground : @(NO)
               } error:&myError];
```

**Swift code**

```
var myError: NSError?
let webServer = GCDWebServer()
webServer.startWithOptions([GCDWebServerOption_AutomaticallySuspendInBackground : false], error: myError)
```

**A little tip:** if you want to change the GCDWebServer log level you can use the static method:

```
[GCDWebServer setLogLevel:4];
```

Comment: yes I was able to set the variable this way. But I am not seeing any change in the server suspension. It still does suspend when in background. I am using the webuploader - it wont work that way? Will be doing more reading on it. I am adding this as the answer meanwhile. Thank you!

Comment: Once I got the it working with iOS 7 by disabling the system idle timer: `[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;`. I'm not quite sure, though, if it works correctly with newer iOSes since they introduced a better energy control.